# How can I create a bar chart using columns from two separate data frames?

Tags: python, matplotlib, dataframe, bar-chart

I am trying to create a horizontal bar chart that has two color categories, one for 2015 and one for 2016. The dataframes look like this:

```
mc_math_sorted_districts15
Out[98]: 
       Both Met and Exceeded                           District Name
31943                    0.0              San Lucas Union Elementary
733                      7.0     Monterey County Office Of Education
13578                    9.0  South Monterey County Joint Union High
42319                   12.0                        Gonzales Unified
3130                    13.0                            Alisal Union
31427                   13.0               San Ardo Union Elementary
23746                   14.0                 Salinas City Elementary
36709                   14.0           North Monterey County Unified

mc_math_sorted_districts16
Out[99]: 
       Both Met and Exceeded                             District Name
31990                    3.0                San Lucas Union Elementary
31491                    8.0                 San Ardo Union Elementary
735                      9.0       Monterey County Office Of Education
13584                   13.0  South Monterey County Joint Union High S
23727                   15.0                   Salinas City Elementary
11936                   16.0           King City Union School District
42534                   16.0          Gonzales Unified School District
10563                   16.0               Greenfield Union Elementary
36782                   17.0  North Monterey County Unified School Dis
```

I want the x-axis of the chart to be the "Both Met and Exceeded" column (a different color for each data frame). I have been using the following code, but I can only plot one dataframe at a time.

```
ax = mc_math_sorted_districts15[['Both Met and Exceeded']].plot(kind='barh', title ="Percentage Met or Exceeded by District-Math 2015", figsize=(15, 10), legend=True, fontsize=12)
ax.set_xlabel("Percentage Met or Exceeded", fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel("District Name", fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

Is there a way to add both columns in the same plot?

Comment: You want the *x* axis to to be the "met and exceeded column"?  Then what do you want the Y axis to be?

Comment: Yes, and the y-axis to be "District Name," which both dataframes have in common. (In the snapshot I provided, the district names don't appear the same in both data frames, but in my dataset they are)

Comment: If they are the same, then why not just join the two into one DataFrame and then use `.plot.barh(x='District Name", y=["Met1", "Met2"])`?

Comment: Yes that worked, thank you!